# Is it possible in Adobe Reader to be able to be in touch mode AND have a scroll bar that doesn't disappear?

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader

For Windows 8.1 on a Surface Pro 3 using Adobe Reader XI 11.0.10.

If I disable touch mode, the scroll bar permanently appears but I'm now not able to touch to scroll. If I enable touch mode, the scroll bar only appears if I touch the screen. Then 3 seconds later, the scroll bar will auto hide itself.

I know it's possible to have touch and the permanent scroll bar at the same time; you need to press the "Toggle Touch Mode" button. However, I don't want to have to inform the users to do this every time. There doesn't seem to be a preference/option in Adobe Reader itself that does what I want.

Some background info: this is for a WPF application that uses a WebBrowser object to display a PDF via Adobe Reader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the Adobe Reader version to DC and it works like I want.